# Assert that submodule always pointed to a valid commit

Tags: git

A [common mistake](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) with submodules is to commit in the superproject a subproject hash pointing at a commit that isn't reachable by everybody using the superproject (for instance, the commit may only exist on someone's personal machine.)

I would like to audit an entire history to make sure that every subproject commit ever referenced by the superproject actually exists in a given remote repository.  Is there a good way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this [GitHub project **`git-pre-push-submodule-check`**](https://github.com/ktoso/git-pre-push-submodule-check) (from [Konrad Malawski aka ktoso](https://github.com/ktoso)) which does the check (ruby script):

> From now on, you may want to use pom instead of other push methods, here's how it would look like:
>
> When you have unpushed changes in submodules:

```
$ git pom
Checking [styles-common] submodule for unpushed commits...
**********************************************************
  You have 2 unpushed commits within styles-common:
  1a87491 added more fluffy icons
  bd40c09 flash now has nice round corners
**********************************************************
Aborting push.
```

> When you don't have unpushed changes in submodules:

```
$ ./check_submodule_pushed.rb
Checking [styles-common] submodule for unpushed commits...
Seems all submodule commits you refer to are reachable, let's push!
```

But my point is: I don't know of a native way of checking if a submodule has been push before pushing its parent repo.

Comment: Thanks, neat project.  If I understand correctly, this is a sanity check on new commits - how about if you want to audit an existing history?

Comment: @gcbenison I think (not tested yet) you can apply it on an existing project: it will detect if your submodules has unpushed commits (even though your parent repo might have nothing to push)